# Redirection to Mobile Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a webpage that detects screen width and then redirects mobile users to a mobile html made by jQuery Mobile. But this way, some samsung phone users seem to have errors, and users don't get an option to view the desktop site. My current code is this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "mobilehome.html";
}
//-->
    </script>
    <script language=javascript>
<!--
        if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
            window.location = "http://viewplus.url.ph/mobilehome.html";}


    </script>
```

and I want to get a website that can redirect users to the mobile webpage but I want them to have an option to view the desktop page too. (Like a "desktop" button) I know it's possible but I don't know how ! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to try and identify if a device is mobile by its resolution or screen size, as those can vary greatly.

[Here](https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile) is a great plugin that gives you an object you can easily check if the users' device is mobile or not. Simply include this plugin in your code, after which you could do

```
if( isMobile.any ) window.location = "mobilehome.html";
```

There are also a tonne of other options to target specific devices.

Comment: No, nothing says the plugin needs jQuery to work. Are you sure you included the plugin correctly?

Comment: Also, see the update to my answer, you should use the `window` object to redirect pages.